# SharePoint Online Change "New Item" title on NewForm.ASPX

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office

I have been really trying to figure this issue out and can not seem to find the right answer.

I have a SharePoint form that is customized with Microsoft PowerApps, and when you navigate to the form with NewForm.aspx it will always list New item at the top like so:

[image]

I have tried editing this with SharePoint Designer but I can not change it that way. I just need to change New item to something meaningful.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've the same question. Here's some insights to help drive to an answer:
> the issue seems to be how SP is handling allowing the editing of the NewForm.aspx page. In one view, you can add a script web part which will give you the ability to change "New Item" (there's a few articles about this but it's basically a DOM detection, innerhtml replacement workaround - not sure why it's not a variable...). But, for some reason, once you change the form type to a powerapps form, that option to add a web part work around goes away. You "can" edit the NewForm.aspx in one view - but that only changes the

Answer (score 1):

Use the following JSON to customize

```
{
    "txtContent": "Demande d'absence",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "border": "none",
        "background-color": "transparent",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "color": "black",
        "font-size": "20px",
        "font-weight": "bold"
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the result:

[image: try us]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement. I customized my list in Power Apps. If you are not willing to use Power Apps, change List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> List Experience to Classic experience and script in newform.aspx